# Circle bounce bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, safari

I'm creating a minigame using HTML5 and jQuery without canvas (!) and, while developing the bounce part (when circle collide with stage limit), I found a bug:

When the circle collides with the bottom or right limits and you keep pressing the down/right arrow key, the circle continues bouncing with the stage limit, but when you do the same thing with the opposite stage limits (top and left), the circle bounce one or two times, and then stops (I want to get the second reaction, when it bounce and then stop). **I've also discovered that this bug only occur in Safari.** Can someone help me to solve it?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/bp8nd/)

[**Demo on site**](http://escherparkour.com/veljs3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>VelJS 3 Pre-Alpha</title>

    <!-- This app was coded by Tiago Marinho -->
    <!-- Special thanks to Drizr, from the interwebs -->
    <!-- Do not leech it! -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i.imgur.com/Jja8mvg.png">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var yvel = 0, xvel = 0;
    var up = false, // W or arrow up
            left = false, // A or arrow left
            right = false, // D or arrow right
            down = false; // S or arrow down

            // Keydown:
            document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 87 || evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
                    up = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 65 || evt.keyCode == 37) { // left
                    left = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 68 || evt.keyCode == 39) { // right
                    right = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 83 || evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
                    down = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 80) { // del/p
                }
            });
            // Keyup:
            document.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 87 || evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
                    up = false;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 65 || evt.keyCode == 37) { // left
                    left = false;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 68 || evt.keyCode == 39) { // right
                    right = false;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 83 || evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
                    down = false;
                }
            });

            function y(obj){
                return $(obj).offset().top;
            }
            function x(obj){
                return $(obj).offset().left;
            }

            setInterval(function(){

                // Keydown/keyup handler:
                if (up == true) {
                    yvel -= 2;
                } else {
                    if (yvel < 0) {
                        yvel++;
                    }
                }
                if (left == true) {
                    xvel -= 2;
                } else {
                    if (xvel < 0) {
                        xvel++;
                    }
                }
                if (right == true) {
                    xvel += 2;
                } else {
                    if (xvel > 0) {
                        xvel--;
                    }
                }
                if (down == true) {
                    yvel += 2;
                } else {
                    if (yvel > 0) {
                        yvel--;
                    }
                }

                var nextposx = $("circle").offset().left+xvel/16;
                var nextposy = $("circle").offset().top+yvel/16;

                if(nextposy < 0 || nextposy+20 > window.innerHeight){
                    yvel = Math.round(yvel*-0.5);
                }
                if(nextposx < 0 || nextposx+20 > window.innerWidth){
                    console.log(xvel);
                    xvel = Math.round(xvel*-0.5);
                    console.log(xvel);
                }
                $("circle").css({
                    top:$("circle").offset().top+yvel/16,
                    left:$("circle").offset().left+xvel/16
                });
            },8);
    </script>
    <style>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> * {
            margin: 0;
        }
        html,
        body {
            -webkit-text-smoothing: antialiased;
            height:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #181818;
        }
        circle{
            position:absolute;

            top:0;
            left:0;

            width:20px;
            height:20px;

            border-radius:10px;
            background:#fff;
        }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <circle></circle>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not using canvas because I've already tried to create this minigame using EaselJS, but I found lots of problems and there's no reason to use it in my case, since this game doesn't have any images (then there's no need for hardware acceleration).

Comment: That's a real stumper. Which behaviour are you going for? The infinite bouncing?

Comment: No, I'm looking for when it stops after bouncing. (The problem is when it bounces infinitely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a full update of a previous non-working answer.
The complete code of the answer is available at the bottom.

I had to check all browser to see what were the problems:

-On Chrome all were working perfectly so I had nothing to change.

-On Safari the ball was bouncing on the bottom and on the right. I figured out that the problem was caused by a position which was set in float and not in int so I just had to round the displacement.

```
$("circle").css({
top:Math.round($("circle").offset().top+yvel/16),
left:Math.round($("circle").offset().left+xvel/16)
});
```

My first answer was resolving the problem by cheating in displacements, this time the answer fix it. This amelioration shouldn't affect Chrome (but I can't test it now).

-On Firefox the ball was stopping before the bottom of the page. I just had to change comparators for collision by the body and add a `margin` of `0px` to it.
In older versions of Firefox, when you press UP the ball was going a little DOWN before going UP, I his this bug is due to the `xvel--`, `xvel++`, `yvel--` and `yvel++` that are faster than  `xvel+=2`, `xvel-=2`, `yvel+=2` and `yvel-=2` so I replace them by two times `++xvel`, two times `--xvel`, two times `++yvel` and two times `--yvel` which should be faster (again I can't test it right now so I hope this is working). These amelioration should't affect Chrome and Safari.

Then I optimise your code to make it more efficient.

Your HTML hasn't change.

Your css is now:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> * {
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body {
            -webkit-text-smoothing: antialiased;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #181818;
            margin: 0px;
        }

    circle {
        position:absolute;  
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        border-radius:10px;
        background:#fff;
    }
```

Your JavaScript is now:

```
var yvel = 0, xvel = 0;
    var up = false, // W or arrow up
            left = false, // A or arrow left
            right = false, // D or arrow right
            down = false; // S or arrow down

            // Keydown:
            document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 87 || evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
                    up = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 65 || evt.keyCode == 37) { // left
                    left = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 68 || evt.keyCode == 39) { // right
                    right = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 83 || evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
                    down = true;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 80) { // del/p
                }
            });
            // Keyup:
            document.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 87 || evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
                    up = false;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 65 || evt.keyCode == 37) { // left
                    left = false;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 68 || evt.keyCode == 39) { // right
                    right = false;
                }
                if (evt.keyCode == 83 || evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
                    down = false;
                }
            });

            function y(obj){
                return $(obj).offset().top;
            }
            function x(obj){
                return $(obj).offset().left;
            }

            setInterval(function(){

                // Keydown/keyup handler:
                if (up) {
                    --yvel;
                    --yvel;
                } else if (yvel < 0) {
                        yvel++;
                }
                if (left) {
                    --xvel;
                    --xvel;
                } else if (xvel < 0) {
                        xvel++;
                }
                if (right) {
                    ++xvel;
                    ++xvel;
                } else if (xvel > 0) {
                        xvel--;
                }
                if (down) {
                    ++yvel;
                    ++yvel;
                } else if (yvel > 0) {
                    yvel--;
                }

                var nextposx = $("circle").offset().left+xvel/16;
                var nextposy = $("circle").offset().top+yvel/16;

                if(nextposy < 0 || nextposy+20 > $('body').height()){
                    yvel = Math.round(yvel*-0.5);
                }
                if(nextposx < 0 || nextposx+20 > $('body').width()){
                    xvel = Math.round(xvel*-0.5);
                }
                $('circle').css({
                    top:Math.round($('circle').offset().top+yvel/16),
                    left:Math.round($('circle').offset().left+xvel/16)
                });
            },8);
```

You have a JSFiddle of the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bp8nd/132/).

The only error that remain is that in Firefox the circle exceeds of few pixels at the right but it's very minimal.

Sorry if my english is bad, I hope you get all what I write.
I think my job here is done...
Have fun with that =D.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Worked like a charm in Safari 7, but now there's a bug in Chrome. If the circle bouces with the right or bottom stage limit and you continue pressing right/bottom, the circle go through it slowly.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I just try this code on Firefox and it's completely broken... So you can keep your first version, I'll check a solution later but I can't do it for now.

Comment: No problem. I'm working on the canvas version of this minigame while this problem isn't solved, but if you can help me later I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Sorry I was busy in a big project... I updated my whole answer, I hope this will help you. Have a nice day !